# Xcode slow compile time on equatable protocol

Tags: xcode, compiler-optimization, equatable

Xcode is taking too long to compile class's with equatable protocol, this is a little strange because in this particular case it's only comparing primitive types, this should be easy.

Took 608ms to type-check this:

```
    public static func == (lhs: TheModel, rhs: TheModel) -> Bool {
    return lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName &&
        lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName &&
        lhs.maritalStatus == rhs.maritalStatus &&
        lhs.sex == rhs.sex &&
        lhs.birthDate == rhs.birthDate &&
        lhs.nationality == rhs.nationality &&
        lhs.hasAnotherNationality == rhs.hasAnotherNationality &&
        lhs.anotherNationality == rhs.anotherNationality &&
        lhs.nif == rhs.nif &&
        lhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress == rhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress &&
        lhs.identificationCard == rhs.identificationCard &&
        lhs.identificationCardNumber == rhs.identificationCardNumber &&
        lhs.identificationCardExpirationDate == rhs.identificationCardExpirationDate &&
        lhs.education == rhs.education &&
        lhs.jobTitle == rhs.jobTitle &&
        lhs.patronalEntity == rhs.patronalEntity &&
        lhs.hasLivesOfIncomes == rhs.hasLivesOfIncomes &&
        lhs.permanentAddressContainer == rhs.permanentAddressContainer &&
        lhs.fiscalAddressContainer == rhs.fiscalAddressContainer &&
        lhs.placeOfBirth == rhs.placeOfBirth &&
        lhs.honorificTitle == rhs.honorificTitle &&
        lhs.userType == rhs.userType &&
        lhs.userTypeDescription == rhs.userTypeDescription &&
        lhs.lastVisitedCountryCode == rhs.lastVisitedCountryCode &&
        lhs.lastUpdate == rhs.lastUpdate
}
```

PS:I know this comparison it's a little overkill but it's only an example.
By the way, this was in MacbookPro with core i9, 64Gb of RAM and SSD.

**Update - I made some changes and run some more tests:**

***Test 1***

Added explicit type to a let and returned the let: Took ~450ms

```
public static func == (lhs: TheModel, rhs: TheModel) -> Bool {
    let extractedExpr: Bool = lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName &&
        lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName &&
        lhs.maritalStatus == rhs.maritalStatus &&
        lhs.sex == rhs.sex &&
        lhs.birthDate == rhs.birthDate &&
        lhs.nationality == rhs.nationality &&
        lhs.hasAnotherNationality == rhs.hasAnotherNationality &&
        lhs.anotherNationality == rhs.anotherNationality &&
        lhs.nif == rhs.nif &&
        lhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress == rhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress &&
        lhs.identificationCard == rhs.identificationCard &&
        lhs.identificationCardNumber == rhs.identificationCardNumber &&
        lhs.identificationCardExpirationDate == rhs.identificationCardExpirationDate &&
        lhs.education == rhs.education &&
        lhs.jobTitle == rhs.jobTitle &&
        lhs.patronalEntity == rhs.patronalEntity &&
        lhs.hasLivesOfIncomes == rhs.hasLivesOfIncomes &&
        lhs.permanentAddressContainer == rhs.permanentAddressContainer &&
        lhs.fiscalAddressContainer == rhs.fiscalAddressContainer &&
        lhs.placeOfBirth == rhs.placeOfBirth &&
        lhs.honorificTitle == rhs.honorificTitle &&
        lhs.userType == rhs.userType &&
        lhs.userTypeDescription == rhs.userTypeDescription &&
        lhs.lastVisitedCountryCode == rhs.lastVisitedCountryCode &&
        lhs.lastUpdate == rhs.lastUpdate
    
    return extractedExpr
}
```

***Test 2***

Added parenthesis to each case: Same result as Test 1!

```
 let extractedExpr: Bool = (lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName) &&
        (lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName) &&
        (lhs.maritalStatus == rhs.maritalStatus) &&
        (lhs.sex == rhs.sex) &&
        (lhs.birthDate == rhs.birthDate) &&
        (lhs.nationality == rhs.nationality) &&
        (lhs.hasAnotherNationality == rhs.hasAnotherNationality) &&
        (lhs.anotherNationality == rhs.anotherNationality) &&
        (lhs.nif == rhs.nif) &&
        (lhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress == rhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress) &&
        (lhs.identificationCard == rhs.identificationCard) &&
        (lhs.identificationCardNumber == rhs.identificationCardNumber) &&
        (lhs.identificationCardExpirationDate == rhs.identificationCardExpirationDate) &&
        (lhs.education == rhs.education) &&
        (lhs.jobTitle == rhs.jobTitle) &&
        (lhs.patronalEntity == rhs.patronalEntity) &&
        (lhs.hasLivesOfIncomes == rhs.hasLivesOfIncomes) &&
        (lhs.permanentAddressContainer == rhs.permanentAddressContainer) &&
        (lhs.fiscalAddressContainer == rhs.fiscalAddressContainer) &&
        (lhs.placeOfBirth == rhs.placeOfBirth) &&
        (lhs.honorificTitle == rhs.honorificTitle) &&
        (lhs.userType == rhs.userType) &&
        (lhs.userTypeDescription == rhs.userTypeDescription) &&
        (lhs.lastVisitedCountryCode == rhs.lastVisitedCountryCode) &&
        (lhs.lastUpdate == rhs.lastUpdate)

    return extractedExpr
```

***Test 3***

Added a bollean array as var with explicity type and append each condition: Took 171ms :)

```
public static func == (lhs: TheModel, rhs: TheModel) -> Bool {
    var result: [Bool] = [Bool]()

    result.append(lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName)
    result.append(lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName)
    result.append(lhs.maritalStatus == rhs.maritalStatus)
    result.append(lhs.sex == rhs.sex)
    result.append(lhs.birthDate == rhs.birthDate)
    result.append(lhs.nationality == rhs.nationality)
    result.append(lhs.hasAnotherNationality == rhs.hasAnotherNationality)
    result.append(lhs.anotherNationality == rhs.anotherNationality)
    result.append(lhs.nif == rhs.nif)
    result.append(lhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress == rhs.hasAnotherFiscalAddress)
    result.append(lhs.identificationCard == rhs.identificationCard)
    result.append(lhs.identificationCardNumber == rhs.identificationCardNumber)
    result.append(lhs.identificationCardExpirationDate == rhs.identificationCardExpirationDate)
    result.append(lhs.education == rhs.education)
    result.append(lhs.jobTitle == rhs.jobTitle)
    result.append(lhs.patronalEntity == rhs.patronalEntity)
    result.append(lhs.hasLivesOfIncomes == rhs.hasLivesOfIncomes)
    result.append(lhs.permanentAddressContainer == rhs.permanentAddressContainer)
    result.append(lhs.fiscalAddressContainer == rhs.fiscalAddressContainer)
    result.append(lhs.placeOfBirth == rhs.placeOfBirth)
    result.append(lhs.honorificTitle == rhs.honorificTitle)
    result.append(lhs.userType == rhs.userType)
    result.append(lhs.userTypeDescription == rhs.userTypeDescription)
    result.append(lhs.lastVisitedCountryCode == rhs.lastVisitedCountryCode)
    result.append(lhs.lastUpdate == rhs.lastUpdate)

    return !result.contains(false)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it’s a very long expression. The compiler doesn’t like that. Build it up out of pairs assigned to Bool variables explicitly.

Comment: I extracted to an expression like: let extractedExpr: Bool = lhs.test == rhs.test ....... return extractedExpr. But even like this, it took 400ms. I will try next with pairs, any other suggestions?

Comment: You didn’t do what I said (until you got to test 3).

Comment: Yes I know  I decided to try a few things first. Your suggestion was the best result so I posted last until to be like some kind of reward